# Error with ProcessStartInfo (run batch file)

Tags: c#, windows-server-2008

we inherited some code and it is running fine on a windows server 2003 machine and on my windows 7 64bit machine. When I deploy it to a windows server 2008 R2 machine the code doesn't run and it might have something with permissions to do.

The code is (in an ASP.NET web service):

```
public static void RunBatch(string file)
{
    try
    {
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo;
        Process batchExecute;

            startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(file);
            startInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\batch";
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

            startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

            startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            batchExecute = new Process();
            batchExecute.StartInfo = startInfo;

            batchExecute.Start();
            batchExecute.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            batchExecute.WaitForExit();
            batchExecute.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.WriteOutputLog("Exception in RunBatch: " + ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
```

and when it gets invoked it just 'stops', nothing happens but no exception is raised.

Any suggestions on what might this piece of code to not run on a windows server 2008 without some configuration?

Thanks in advance.

Update:
it stops at

```
batchExecute.WaitForExit();
```

It starts an FTP process (that doesn't seem to be able to download files)

```
ftp -s:"C:\Batch\Commands.txt" ipNumber
```

the ftp process tries to download a file and on my machine it works fine but on the server it stops at
150 Opening Binary mode data connection for  fileName fileSize

It can connect to the FTP though and I can browser to it through the browser on the server without issues.

Comment: First try running it manually... If that works, try hooking into the output and error streams for the Process and logging that to console/a file

Comment: Stops like never completes? If so which line of code does it stop on?

Comment: Hi, I updated my first post a bit.

Comment: If the ftp command doesn't exit then it makes sense that WaitForExit keeps waiting.  It sounds like a permissions problem as you guessed, or maybe a firewall problem.  Since the command line ftp command listens on the network, you might need to set the firewall to let it listen.